# Bash multiple port mapping depending on script argument

Tags: bash, docker

I have a script that accepts as an argument; then my script has to create a docker container with a number of port mapping depending on this argument; for example, if i run .`/myscript.sh 10`, myscript.sh has to create a docker container with 10 port mapping.

This is my myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

NCACHES=$1
PORT_BASE=80

docker run -idt --name CONTAINER   then..?
```

If argument value is, for example, 5, i would that myscript creates a container with port mapping 80,81,82,83,84. How could i manage this condition in bash script?

With argument value=5, it's expected to have: docker run -idt --name MYNAME -p 80:80 -p 81:81 -p 82:82 -p 83:83 -p 84:84

edit: i've tried my script :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1

docker run -idt --name CONTAINER `for x in {80..$(( 80 + ${1} ))}; do printf "-p ${x}:${x} "; done` pier92/balancer:latest
```

but this is output:

```
./mapping.sh 5
5
./mapping.sh: riga 9: printf: -p: opzione non valida
printf: uso: printf [-v var] formato [argomenti]
75899b1ec4edab51530ad8c33e955a31a45fb946ecc6eb2fa3f1ba5b5537064a
pierpaolo@pignasecca:~/Scrivania/setup-arch/webapp$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                 NAMES
75899b1ec4ed        pier92/balancer:latest       "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   7 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        80/tcp, 443/tcp                                                                                       CONTAINER
```

there is only port 80 mapped.

Comment: How are you passing these port mappings to `docker`?

Comment: with argument value=5, it's expected to have: docker run -idt --name MYNAME -p 80:80 -p 81:81 -p 82:82 -p 83:83 -p 84:84

Comment: I think that what you're asking now is easily done changing a bit the code, you should try it by yourself so you'll learn more!

Comment: i've just solved my last question myself. Thanks to all!

Comment: @pier92 Stop adding to your already-answered. Post a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather use an array and pass manipulate the contents inside,

```
portArr=()
for ((i=0;i<NCACHES;i++)); do 
    portArr+=( -p "$((PORT_BASE+i)):$((PORT_BASE+i))")
done
```

once the array is populated, you can verify its contents by printing

```
declare -p portArr
```

which shows the values per index,

```
declare -a portArr='([0]="-p" [1]="80:80" [2]="-p" [3]="81:81" [4]="-p" [5]="82:82" [6]="-p" [7]="83:83" [8]="-p" [9]="84:84")'
```

and now pass it to the `docker` command as

```
docker run -idt --name MYNAME "${portArr[@]}"
```

Comment: `-p` and the pair of ports need to be separate elements of the array. `portArr+=( -p "$((PORT_BASE+i)):$((PORT_BASE+i))")`

Comment: @chepner: Thanks! have made use of your suggestion!

Comment: @Inian i've edited my question, for doing the same thing but in docker swarm in host mode.

Comment: @pier92: Am afraid, you'll have to ask it as a separate one. With answers provided, you are _not_ supposed to ask new ones

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through a sequence thus:

```
for i in $(seq 1 $1); do 
   echo $i; 
done
```

which will loop between 1 and your input numeric argument. You can append to a string representing your command line within the above.

Note that you can expand ranges in bash between fixed values using `${1..5}` (say) but this doesn't work when using variables in the range.

Comment: Don't use `seq`; it's not part of the POSIX standard, so in `bash` you may as well just use a C-style `for` loop `for ((i=1; i<=$1; i++)); do`. If you need POSIX compatibility, use `i=1; while [ "$i" -le "$1" ]; do ...; i=$((i+1)); done`

Comment: I take your point re. POSIX, but I confess it's something I rarely worry about and haven't ever been bitten by. e.g. I've just surveyed my dev environment and prod servers, and all have /usr/bin/seq. I'd be interested to see how many people are impacted by such scenarios

Comment: I take the view that answers here should strive to be "overly" correct, since you don't know who might try to use the answer. From a more practical standpoint, why generate a (possibly very long) list of numbers in memory if you don't need to?

Comment: I think those are both very valid comments

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
docker run -idt --name CONTAINER `for x in {80..$(( 80 + ${1} ))}; do printf "$x "; done`
```

Output would be something like:

```
docker run -idt --name CONTAINER 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
```

Explaination:

It's just a inline for which print the sequence of numbers.

To do sums and so in bash you use this syntax `$(( x + y ))` .

---

Edit:

Just add in the printf everything you need to display, in this case would be:

```
docker run -idt --name CONTAINER `for x in $(seq 80 $(( 80 + ${1} )) ); do printf " -p ${x}:${x}"; done`
```

which output for example:

```
docker run -idt --name CONTAINER -p 80:80 -p 81:81 -p 82:82 -p 83:83 -p 84:84 -p 85:85 -p 86:86 -p 87:87 -p 88:88 -p 89:89 -p 90:90
```

---

As Brian Agnew pointed out, you have to use $( seq x y ) with variables, thanks!

Comment: i've edited my question. For each port there is a "-p" flag. See my example.

Comment: There you have, maybe there is a better way to do it but that should work

Comment: Does that variable expansion in the range actually work? It doesn't expand on the command line as I'd expect

Comment: My fault, I was doing it in zsh, let me try if it works in bash

Comment: My fault, try now, it must have a space between `"` and `-p` in the printf